# Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm in C - changing paramateres problem

Tags: c, algorithm

this program is made to calculate shortest path between two vertexs. FUnction add_edge is adding edges and also their distance in format `add_edge(g, 1, 2, 7);`where first parameter is linked list, second and third paramater are edges and last one is distance between them.

Problem is that my program was made to insert it in this format `add_edge(g, 'a', 'b', 7);`but sending it as integer and in function making it to number with this action `int a = a - 'a';`.

and after i transformed my code to sending numbers instead of characters it stopped to work. showing no error but returning tash numbers.

Here's old code(working):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    int weight;
} edge_t;

typedef struct {
    edge_t **edges;
    int edges_len;
    int edges_size;
    int dist;
    int prev;
    int visited;
} vertex_t;

typedef struct {
    vertex_t **vertices;
    int vertices_len;
    int vertices_size;
} graph_t;

typedef struct {
    int *data;
    int *prio;
    int *index;
    int len;
    int size;
} heap_t;

void add_vertex (graph_t *g, int i) {
    int j;
    if (g->vertices_size < i + 1) {
        int size = g->vertices_size * 2 > i ? g->vertices_size * 2 : i + 4;
        g->vertices = realloc(g->vertices, size * sizeof (vertex_t *));
        for (j = g->vertices_size; j < size; j++)
            g->vertices[j] = NULL;
        g->vertices_size = size;
    }
    if (!g->vertices[i]) {
        g->vertices[i] = calloc(1, sizeof (vertex_t));
        g->vertices_len++;
    }
}

void add_edge (graph_t *g, int a, int b, int w) {
    a = a - 'a';
    b = b - 'a';
    add_vertex(g, a);
    add_vertex(g, b);
    vertex_t *v = g->vertices[a];
    if (v->edges_len >= v->edges_size) {
        v->edges_size = v->edges_size ? v->edges_size * 2 : 4;
        v->edges = realloc(v->edges, v->edges_size * sizeof (edge_t *));
    }
    edge_t *e = calloc(1, sizeof (edge_t));
    e->vertex = b;
    e->weight = w;
    v->edges[v->edges_len++] = e;
}

heap_t *create_heap (int n) {
    heap_t *h = calloc(1, sizeof (heap_t));
    h->data = calloc(n + 1, sizeof (int));
    h->prio = calloc(n + 1, sizeof (int));
    h->index = calloc(n, sizeof (int));
    return h;
}

void push_heap (heap_t *h, int v, int p) {
    int i = h->index[v] == 0 ? ++h->len : h->index[v];
    int j = i / 2;
    while (i > 1) {
        if (h->prio[j] < p)
            break;
        h->data[i] = h->data[j];
        h->prio[i] = h->prio[j];
        h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
        i = j;
        j = j / 2;
    }
    h->data[i] = v;
    h->prio[i] = p;
    h->index[v] = i;
}

int min (heap_t *h, int i, int j, int k) {
    int m = i;
    if (j <= h->len && h->prio[j] < h->prio[m])
        m = j;
    if (k <= h->len && h->prio[k] < h->prio[m])
        m = k;
    return m;
}

int pop_heap (heap_t *h) {
    int v = h->data[1];
    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        int j = min(h, h->len, 2 * i, 2 * i + 1);
        if (j == h->len)
            break;
        h->data[i] = h->data[j];
        h->prio[i] = h->prio[j];
        h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
        i = j;
    }
    h->data[i] = h->data[h->len];
    h->prio[i] = h->prio[h->len];
    h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
    h->len--;
    return v;
}

void dijkstra (graph_t *g, int a, int b) {
    int i, j;
    a = a - 'a';
    b = b - 'a';
    for (i = 0; i < g->vertices_len; i++) {
        vertex_t *v = g->vertices[i];
        v->dist = INT_MAX;
        v->prev = 0;
        v->visited = 0;
    }
    vertex_t *v = g->vertices[a];
    v->dist = 0;
    heap_t *h = create_heap(g->vertices_len);
    push_heap(h, a, v->dist);
    while (h->len) {
        i = pop_heap(h);
        if (i == b)
            break;
        v = g->vertices[i];
        v->visited = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < v->edges_len; j++) {
            edge_t *e = v->edges[j];
            vertex_t *u = g->vertices[e->vertex];
            if (!u->visited && v->dist + e->weight <= u->dist) {
                u->prev = i;
                u->dist = v->dist + e->weight;
                push_heap(h, e->vertex, u->dist);
            }
        }
    }
    v = g->vertices[i];
    printf("%d\n", v->dist);
}


int main () {
    graph_t *g = calloc(1, sizeof (graph_t));
    add_edge(g, 'a', 'b', 7);
    add_edge(g, 'a', 'c' ,9); 
    dijkstra(g, 'a', 'c');
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my new code(that i want to make work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    int weight;
} edge_t;

typedef struct {
    edge_t **edges;
    int edges_len;
    int edges_size;
    int dist;
    int prev;
    int visited;
} vertex_t;

typedef struct {
    vertex_t **vertices;
    int vertices_len;
    int vertices_size;
} graph_t;

typedef struct {
    int *data;
    int *prio;
    int *index;
    int len;
    int size;
} heap_t;

void add_vertex (graph_t *g, int i) {
    int j;
    if (g->vertices_size < i + 1) {
        int size = g->vertices_size * 2 > i ? g->vertices_size * 2 : i + 4;
        g->vertices = realloc(g->vertices, size * sizeof (vertex_t *));
        for (j = g->vertices_size; j < size; j++)
            g->vertices[j] = NULL;
        g->vertices_size = size;
    }
    if (!g->vertices[i]) {
        g->vertices[i] = calloc(1, sizeof (vertex_t));
        g->vertices_len++;
    }
}

void add_edge (graph_t *g, int a, int b, int w) {
    add_vertex(g, a);
    add_vertex(g, b);
    vertex_t *v = g->vertices[a];
    if (v->edges_len >= v->edges_size) {
        v->edges_size = v->edges_size ? v->edges_size * 2 : 4;
        v->edges = realloc(v->edges, v->edges_size * sizeof (edge_t *));
    }
    edge_t *e = calloc(1, sizeof (edge_t));
    e->vertex = b;
    e->weight = w;
    v->edges[v->edges_len++] = e;
}

heap_t *create_heap (int n) {
    heap_t *h = calloc(1, sizeof (heap_t));
    h->data = calloc(n + 1, sizeof (int));
    h->prio = calloc(n + 1, sizeof (int));
    h->index = calloc(n, sizeof (int));
    return h;
}

void push_heap (heap_t *h, int v, int p) {
    int i = h->index[v] == 0 ? ++h->len : h->index[v];
    int j = i / 2;
    while (i > 1) {
        if (h->prio[j] < p)
            break;
        h->data[i] = h->data[j];
        h->prio[i] = h->prio[j];
        h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
        i = j;
        j = j / 2;
    }
    h->data[i] = v;
    h->prio[i] = p;
    h->index[v] = i;
}

int min (heap_t *h, int i, int j, int k) {
    int m = i;
    if (j <= h->len && h->prio[j] < h->prio[m])
        m = j;
    if (k <= h->len && h->prio[k] < h->prio[m])
        m = k;
    return m;
}

int pop_heap (heap_t *h) {
    int v = h->data[1];
    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        int j = min(h, h->len, 2 * i, 2 * i + 1);
        if (j == h->len)
            break;
        h->data[i] = h->data[j];
        h->prio[i] = h->prio[j];
        h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
        i = j;
    }
    h->data[i] = h->data[h->len];
    h->prio[i] = h->prio[h->len];
    h->index[h->data[i]] = i;
    h->len--;
    return v;
}

void dijkstra (graph_t *g, int a, int b) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < g->vertices_len; i++) {
        vertex_t *v = g->vertices[i];
        v->dist = INT_MAX;
        v->prev = 0;
        v->visited = 0;
    }
    vertex_t *v = g->vertices[a];
    v->dist = 0;
    heap_t *h = create_heap(g->vertices_len);
    push_heap(h, a, v->dist);
    while (h->len) {
        i = pop_heap(h);
        if (i == b)
            break;
        v = g->vertices[i];
        v->visited = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < v->edges_len; j++) {
            edge_t *e = v->edges[j];
            vertex_t *u = g->vertices[e->vertex];
            if (!u->visited && v->dist + e->weight <= u->dist) {
                u->prev = i;
                u->dist = v->dist + e->weight;
                push_heap(h, e->vertex, u->dist);
            }
        }
    }
    v = g->vertices[i];
    printf("%d\n", v->dist);
}


int main () {
    graph_t *g = calloc(1, sizeof (graph_t));
    add_edge(g, 1, 2, 7);
    add_edge(g, 1, 3 9); 
    dijkstra(g, 1, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

**I would be happy for any suggestion how to make it work even the old one to transform to accept numbers as paramateres and not 'characters'. thanks guys**

Comment: There is an important semantic difference between your two `main()` functions.  The first passes (for example) `'a'` and `'b'` to `add_edge()`, which that function converts to `0` and `1`, respectively, but the corresponding call in the second program passes `1` and `2`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

John Bollinger's comment is right; you are testing different indices.  Inside your dijkstra, you are assuming that the graph is fully populated, when it is really very sparse.   If I have it correctly, you can ignore the nil nodes:

```
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+#include <assert.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <limits.h>
@@ -116,11 +117,17 @@
     int i, j;
     for (i = 0; i < g->vertices_len; i++) {
         vertex_t *v = g->vertices[i];
-        v->dist = INT_MAX;
-        v->prev = 0;
-        v->visited = 0;
+        if (v) {
+            v->dist = INT_MAX;
+            v->prev = 0;
+            v->visited = 0;
+        }
     }
     vertex_t *v = g->vertices[a];
+    if (v == 0) {
+        printf("-1\n");
+        return;
+    }
     v->dist = 0;
     heap_t *h = create_heap(g->vertices_len);
     push_heap(h, a, v->dist);
@@ -129,10 +136,12 @@
         if (i == b)
             break;
         v = g->vertices[i];
+   assert(v);
         v->visited = 1;
         for (j = 0; j < v->edges_len; j++) {
             edge_t *e = v->edges[j];
             vertex_t *u = g->vertices[e->vertex];
+            assert(u);
             if (!u->visited && v->dist + e->weight <= u->dist) {
                 u->prev = i;
                 u->dist = v->dist + e->weight;
@@ -140,8 +149,11 @@
             }
         }
     }
-    v = g->vertices[i];
-    printf("%d\n", v->dist);
+    if (v = g->vertices[i]) {
+        printf("%d\n", v->dist);
+    } else {
+        printf("-2\n");
+    }
 }
```

At the very least, it doesn't fault with your config.